# Probability theory combinatoric problem

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

> A total of $n$ bar magnets are placed end to end in a line with random
>   independent orientations. Adjacent ends with equal polarities repel
>   each other, and adjacent ends with opposite polarities join to form
>   blocks. Let $X$ be the number of blocks of joined magnets. Find $\text{E}(X)$
>   and $\text{Var}(X)$.

The obvious method to solve this problem is to find the pmf of $X$ and then simply use the definitions of the expectancy and variance. I'm however a bit stuck at the first line of this reasoning, i.e. how to find the pmf for $X$.

It feels like somehow a binomial distribution should be involved but the problem is is that there are many ways of creating — for example — two or five blocks out of $n$ magnets, each of which models a binomial distribution. How do I derive a reasonably "clean" pmf for $X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The obvious method to solve this problem is to find the pmf of $X$...

This problem illustrates perfectly that the "obvious method" might not be the easiest. 
Here we can find  $\mathbb{E}(X)$ and $\mathbb{V}(X)$ **without** working out the pmf of $X$.

Instead let's  represent the random variable $X$ with indicator random variables. 
For $i=1,\dots, n-1$ define $Z_i$ to be one if magnets $i$ and $i+1$ repel, 
and zero if they attract. Then the $Z_i$s are independent, and the 
number of blocks satisfies $X=1+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} Z_i.$

Since $\mathbb{E}(Z_i)=1/2$ and $\mathbb{V}(Z_i)=1/4$ we get 
$$\mathbb{E}(X)=1+(n-1)/2={n+1\over 2}\qquad\mbox{and}\qquad  \mathbb{V}(X)={n-1\over 4}.$$

We do not need to calculate any probabilities! This trick is worth remembering,
 and likely what user JiK had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Let $0$ represent one orientation and $1$ represent the other orientation. Each arrangement of the $n$ magnets then corresponds to an $n$-bit binary string. Two adjacent magnets repel if they are in opposite orientations and attract if they are in the same orientation. Thus, a block of magnets corresponds exactly to a block of identical bits. For $n=8$, for instance, the string $00111011$ has $4$ blocks: $00$, $111$, $0$, and $11$. The number of blocks is therefore one more than the total number of $01$ and $10$ transitions.

Suppose that an $n$-bit string has $k$ transitions. There are $\binom{n-1}k$ ways to choose where they occur, and the first bit can be either $0$ or $1$, so there are $2\binom{n-1}k$ such strings. Thus,

$$\Bbb P(X=k)=\frac{2\binom{n-1}{k-1}}{2^n}=\frac1{2^{n-1}}\binom{n-1}{k-1}\;,$$

and

$$\begin{align*}
\Bbb E(X)&=\frac1{2^{n-1}}\sum_{k=1}^nk\binom{n-1}{k-1}\\\\
&=\frac1{2^{n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(k+1)\binom{n-1}k\tag{1}\\\\
&=\frac1{2^{n-1}}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k\binom{n-1}k+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}k\right)\;.
\end{align*}$$

Now observe that $k\dbinom{n-1}k=(n-1)\dbinom{n-2}{k-1}$ and simplify.

**Added:** The variance is $\Bbb E(X^2)-\big(\Bbb E(X)\big)^2$, so we also need to calculate

$$\begin{align*}
\frac1{2^{n-1}}\sum_{k=1}^nk^2\binom{n-1}{k-1}&=\frac1{2^{n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(k+1)^2\binom{n-1}k\\\\
&=\frac1{2^{n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(k^2+2k+1)\binom{n-1}k\\\\
&=\frac1{2^{n-1}}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k^2\binom{n-1}k+2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k\binom{n-1}k+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}k\right)\tag{2}
\end{align*}$$

We’ve already dealt with the last two summations in $(2)$, so all that remains is to deal with

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k^2\binom{n-1}k=(n-1)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k\binom{n-2}{k-1}=(n-1)\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(k+1)\binom{n-2}k\;.\tag{3}$$

The last summation in $(3)$ is essentially just another instance of the summation in $(1)$.

Comment: Before I comment on your answer, I must show my gratitude towards your willingness to invest time into helping people here. I appreciate it a lot, especially since you are a retired professor of mathematics +1. Now for your answer, I do not think think the question defines blocks as you do, rather "adjacent ends with opposite polarities join to form blocks". I think your answer can still be used anyhow, but we will need to differentiate between four cases 1) the binary string starts and ends with 1's 2) the binary string starts with 1's and ends with 0's 3) ... 4) ...

Comment: But all in all this would require a lot of work and this was only a 10 point exam question (for a three hour exam in which 90 points can be achieved, and we haven't even obtained $\text{Var}(X)$ yet). Any thought on this, should I ask my instructor (or show this)? Your solution is quite nice, very simple and elegant. The trick is to rewrite that binomial term to remove the "loose" $k$ inside the summation, clever.

Comment: @Jori: You're very welcome. My blocks really are the same as in the question: $000$ and $111$, for instance, both represent blocks of $3$ magnets with adjacent ends of opposite polarities. There's no need for any more cases than I used: my factor of $2$ accounts for the fact that there are two possible first bits, and the last bit takes care of itself: it's completely determined by the first bit and the number of blocks. For the variance I'd use the formula $\Bbb E(X^2)-(\Bbb E(X))^2$, so that all that remains is to calculate $\Bbb E(X^2)$. I'm headed for bed now, but I'll add something ...

Comment: ... on that when I get back online.

Answer (score 1):

The number of blocks is one plus the number of adjacent ends with equal polarities. Start reading the magnets from the left. What is the probability that the $k+1$th magnet is oriented so that the $k$th and the $k+1$th magnet repel each other, given the orientations of the first $k$ magnets?

Comment: Thank-you for your answer. Unfortunately I do not quite understand what you mean. Could you be a bit more precise please? Note that English is not my first language.